# "Uncaught TypeError: circle is null"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: circle is null" when i'm trying to take mouse click as input. I'm including  my html, css and js code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CSS</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>WHat</h1>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
.circle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
.cicrcle_1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(196, 33, 33);
}
```

JS:

```
console.log(`hello`);

const circle = document.getElementById("circle");
function announce() {
  circle.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  console.log(`clicked`);
  // circle.classList.toggle(".circle_1");
}

circle.addEventListener("click", announce);
```

When i change my  <div **class ="circle"**> to <div **id="circle"**>, and use **(".circle")** in const circle = document.getElementById("circle"); there won't be any error. If i use that as standard, i'm not able to use mouse toggle afterwards. I want to switch between elements of (.circle) and (.circle_1) when i toggle with mouse.

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)